# git origin vs. other remotes, why origin works so much better?

Tags: git, git-push, git-pull, git-remote

When I execute the following commands, everything works fine:

```
git clone x
git checkout master
git pull --rebase
git commit
git push
```

But this does not work and asks for a remote and a branch:

```
git remote add y
git checkout y/master
git pull --rebase
```

I experience similar problems with `git push`.

Why is it not y/origin?
Why does it work so nicely and friendly by default
with `origin` but not other remotes?

Comment: does y exist locally? you might want to try git switch y/master instead of git checkout y/master

Comment: `git remote add y` doesn't specify the actual remote; it should be something along the lines of `git remote add y https://github.com/foo/bar.git`.

Comment: It's not that `origin` as a name works better than `y` as a name (although in practice, it does because so many *humans* are going to assume `origin`). It is instead that once you have *two or more remotes*, things become complicated, as Matt said. Git can no longer guess that `branch-x` goes with `origin/branch-x`, nor can it guess that `branch-x` goes with `y/branch-x`. You're suddenly exposed to all the details of remote-tracking names. Ideally, you should have learned these earlier, before adding the second remote, but not all Git tutorials are good.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because after `git checkout y/master` you are in a **detached HEAD** state. This means you are not currently on a branch and Git does not know what exactly you want to pull. It asks you to specify which branch you want to merge with and proposes the command `git pull <remote> <branch>`. If follow this advice, you fetch the newest state of `<branch>` on `<remote>` and rebase the changes of the current (detached) HEAD on top of it. Probably this is not exactly what you want to achieve since you are still detached.

```
$ git pull --rebase y master
From <y-repository>
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: [...]

$ git status
HEAD detached from y/master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

---

If you want reapply your local changes on the `master` branch on top of `y/master`, there is no need to checkout `y/master` first. Just run `git pull --rebase y master` while `master` is checked out.

---

Git generally does an extremely good job at inferring things for us. As a result, we often use abbreviated forms of commands which results in some default behaviour. With `origin` everything works so smoothly because it is the remote that gets configured automatically when using `git clone` (unless otherwise specified) and as long as this is the only remote, we have no need to tell Git which remote we refer to. When we checkout a branch from a remote, Git automatically sets the remote tracking information which lets you call `git pull` and `git push` without any further arguments. As soon as there are multiple remotes, things get more complicated and may need to be managed manually or by specifying the desired arguments when executing a command. Have a look at [Git Branching - Remote Branches](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches) in the Pro Git book for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the new remote as the upstream when executing the first time using `-u` command (or `--set-upstream`)

```
git push -u y mybranch
```

After this, if you just do `git push` it would automatically be pushed to remote `y`.